# Sort WP_Query->posts Array of Objects conditionally with Different Headers

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, sorting, object

I am having an array of Objects returned by WP_Query->posts

```
array
    0 =>
        object(WP_Post)
              public 'ID' 
              public 'post_title'
              public  'post_content'
   1 =>
        object(WP_Post)
              public 'ID' 
              public 'post_title'
              public  'post_content'
   2 =>
        object(WP_Post)
              public 'ID' 
              public 'post_title'
              public  'post_content'

  3 =>
        object(WP_Post)
              public 'ID' 
              public 'post_title'
              public  'post_content'
 4 =>
        object
              public 'Donor' 
              public 'date'
              public  'post_content'
```

And it goes on ...... I am trying to group this into first, second, third and fourth Quarter based on a `date` meta field  ie; first quarter is the first three months (Jan, Feb ,March ), second quarter will be the next three and so on and give headings ,'First Quarter ,'Second Quarter ' etc:-

I achieved this by

```
<h3> First Quarter </h3>
<?php
     foreach($posts as $q1) {
       $donor_date = get_post_meta($q1->ID,'donor-date',true);
       $donor_month = date('m',strtotime($donor_date));

       if(!in_array($donor_month,array('01','02','03'),true)) continue;
?>
 <tr><td> <?php echo date('d/m/Y',strtotime($donor_date)); ?> </td></tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>

 <h3> Second Quarter </h3>
<?php
     foreach($posts as $q2) {
       $donor_date = get_post_meta($q2->ID,'donor-date',true);
       $donor_month = date('m',strtotime($donor_date));

       if(!in_array($donor_month,array('04','05','06'),true)) continue;
?>
 <tr><td> <?php echo date('d/m/Y',strtotime($donor_date)); ?> </td></tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

and so on  ...... the problem with this approach is that  the headings ( First Quarter, Second Quarter ... ) will be there even if there is not data that meets the given condition . Is there a way to conditionally show and hide the headers too and a better method for sorting ( refactor)  .......

Thanks in advance  ........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to check the values in the array before starting any output.

I'd suggest doing this by saving the data to be displayed in an array instead of 
printing it immediately. Also, assuming `$posts` is the same in every `foreach`, you will only need to loop once.

**Example with step-by-step instructions in the comments**

```
<?php
/* declare an array to save the data */
$quarters = array();

foreach($posts as $q) {

   $donor_date = get_post_meta($q->ID,'donor-date',true);
   $donor_month = date('m',strtotime($donor_date));

   /* format the date once - best practice is not to repeat code */
   $formatteddate = date('d/m/Y',strtotime($donor_date));

   /* organise the dates by quarter, using the heading as the key for easy display */
   if(in_array($donor_month, array('01','02','03')))
       $quarters["First Quarter"][] = $formatteddate;

   else if(in_array($donor_month, array('04','05','06')))
       $quarters["Second Quarter"][] = $formatteddate;

   else if(in_array($donor_month, array('07','08','09')))
       $quarters["Third Quarter"][] = $formatteddate;

   else if(in_array($donor_month, array('10','11','12')))
       $quarters["Fourth Quarter"][] = $formatteddate;
}

 /* now go through your array and display the results */
 foreach ($quarters as $quartername => $quarter){
     /* $quarters won't have any entry for quarters with no dates, so technically this 'if' isn't needed,
       however I've added it in case it will be needed it for any other changes you make */
     if ($quarter){ ?>

         <h3><?php echo $quartername; ?></h3>
         <table>
         <?php  foreach ($quarter as $qdate ){ ?>
             <tr><td> <?php echo $qdate; ?> </td></tr>
         <?php  }  // end foreach($quarter...) ?>
         </table>
     <?php 
     } // end if 
} // end foreach($quarters...) 
?>
```

I'm not sure where your `<table>` element is created,because at the moment the `<h3>`s are added between `<tr>`s which is incorrect - however this mirrors the code you posted, so you should know how to work around that yourself!

Comment: Will try your code and sorry for the broken table structure , as i shortened the code ...... the code was supposed to display donor name, amount  and date , all of which are meta fields and special thanks for the 'refactor' part .... thank you so much  ... will choose as answer once i try it .

Comment: I figured it was because we were only seeing part of your code! If you have more information you can store all in the $quarters array, and then display it later - just build an array and add it to $quarters instead of just the `$formatteddate`, e.g. `$quarters[QUARTER_NAME][] = $array_with_all_info;`. FYI I haven't tested the code in my answer, but the basic logic should be correct. Let me know if you have any problems with it.

Comment: Sure , will do that  ...... will choose this as answer tomorrow once i check it  .....   Thank you once more

Comment: Accepted your answer as it works perfectly  ..... there is some syntax errors like missing a closing bracket for `in_array` and mixing colon\curly braces in `foreach`  ..... Thanks a lot for you kind help

Comment: Glad it worked for you! Sorry about the typos, I was typing it directly in the Answer editor without testing it. I'll update my answer to fix them, just in case someone else might find your question helpful. I'll also add a `<table>` element just so it generates valid HTML (I know you were processing it in your own code, but for anyone else)

Comment: Is there any way to seperate the quarters by year? Like: 2017 -> Quarter 1,2,3,4 and 2018 -> Quarter 1,2,3,4

Answer (score 0):

Put the header inside the for loop and validate the month with if and else if statements to select which header display use one foreach statement

```
<?php
 foreach($posts as $q) {
   $donor_date = get_post_meta($q1->ID,'donor-date',true);
   $donor_month = date('m',strtotime($donor_date));
   if(in_array($donor_month,array('01','02','03'),true)) 
echo "<h3>First Quarter</h3>";
if(!in_array($donor_month,array('04','05','06'),true)
echo "<h3>Second Quarter</h3>";
?>
 <tr><td> <?php echo date('d/m/Y',strtotime($donor_date)); ?> </td></tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Haven't tried it but i think the heading will get repeated as many times as any of the month  ......

Comment: Yes it will you have to create a condition to print the header only one time may be you do this with a bool variable and change its value and validate it with in foreach loop

Comment: Please go through @FluffyKitten s answer