# WordPress: Order WP_Query by custom date field and split the loop after every month

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using a WordPress Custom Post Type to manage and display events on my site.
To sort the events I'm using a custom meta field with the date in it (stored like this: YYYY-MM-DD). I check the meta field against the current date. Like this:

```
$current_date_query = date ('Y-m-d');

$temp = $wp_query; $wp_query= null; $wp_query = new WP_Query();

$wp_query->query(
    array(
       'post_type' => 'event',
       'meta_key' => 'event_date',
       'meta_compare' => '>=',
       'meta_value' => $current_date_query,
       'post_status' => 'publish',
       'posts_per_page' => '99',
       'orderby' => 'meta_value',
       'order' => 'ASC',
       'paged' => $paged
    )
); ?>


... Loop stuff ...

<?php endif; $wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

I now want to add a headline before every new month. Like this:

**January 2018**

- Event 1
- Event 2
- Event 3

**February 2018**

- Event 4
- Event 5

**March 2018**

- Event 5

and so on...

Is there any way to split the loop after every month?
I guess I have to use the month from the meta field but I don't know how.

I tried the following solution (thanks to the comment from @FluffyKitten):

```
<?php

/* declare an array to save the data */
$quarters = array();

foreach($posts as $q) {

    $donor_date = get_post_meta($q->ID,'gid_22',true);
    $donor_month = date('m',strtotime($donor_date));

    /* format the date once - best practice is not to repeat code */
    $formatteddate = date('d/m/Y',strtotime($donor_date));

    /* organise the dates by quarter, using the heading as the key for easy display */
    if(in_array($donor_month, array('01')))
       $quarters["January"][] = $formatteddate;

    else if(in_array($donor_month, array('02')))
       $quarters["February"][] = $formatteddate;

    else if(in_array($donor_month, array('03')))
       $quarters["March"][] = $formatteddate;

    else if(in_array($donor_month, array('04')))
       $quarters["April"][] = $formatteddate;

    else if(in_array($donor_month, array('05')))
       $quarters["May"][] = $formatteddate;

    else if(in_array($donor_month, array('06')))
       $quarters["June"][] = $formatteddate;

    else if(in_array($donor_month, array('07')))
       $quarters["July"][] = $formatteddate;

    else if(in_array($donor_month, array('08')))
       $quarters["August"][] = $formatteddate;

    else if(in_array($donor_month, array('09')))
       $quarters["September"][] = $formatteddate;

    else if(in_array($donor_month, array('10')))
       $quarters["Ocotber"][] = $formatteddate;

    else if(in_array($donor_month, array('11')))
       $quarters["November"][] = $formatteddate;

    else if(in_array($donor_month, array('12')))
       $quarters["December"][] = $formatteddate;
}

 /* now go through your array and display the results */
 foreach ($quarters as $quartername => $quarter){
     /* $quarters won't have any entry for quarters with no dates, so technically this 'if' isn't needed,
       however I've added it in case it will be needed it for any other changes you make */
     if ($quarter){ ?>

         <h3><?php echo $quartername; ?></h3>
         <table>
         <?php  foreach ($quarter as $qdate ){ ?>
             <tr><td> <?php echo $qdate; ?> </td></tr>
         <?php  }  // end foreach($quarter...) ?>
         </table>
     <?php
     } // end if
} // end foreach($quarters...)
?>
```

Now I get a result like this:

**Ocotber**

- 02/10/2018
- 29/10/2017

**January**

- 02/01/2018

**December**

- 02/12/2017
- 01/12/2017

**May**

- 02/05/2018

...

The order is based on the post date and not based on the custom field.
Also there is no difference between years. The year 2017 should have it's own loop as well as 2018.

If I try to put my own array in the first array of the loop, it has no effect and it only shows as text in the frontend.

Edit: I could order the month by using a custom query like this:

```
$posts = query_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'meta_key' => 'event_date',
    'meta_compare' => '>=',
    'meta_value' => $current_date_query,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => '99',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'paged' => $paged
) );
```

The problem now is only the year. It's all sort by month with different years per month.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort WP\_Query->posts Array of Objects conditionally with Different Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46380987/sort-wp-query-posts-array-of-objects-conditionally-with-different-headers)

Comment: thanks, I will try it

Comment: thanks @FluffyKitten but I couldn't get it to work. I've updated the code in my question. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you tried from @FluffyKitten doesn't work properly because it groups into groups of the same month, not the same month and year so falls over when there are posts in the same month of different years

As @ChinLeung suggested you need to store the current month in a variable to test when it has changed and output your headers. To implement this for your example you would do the following:

```
// Set current month
$current_month = '';

// Get event posts in order
$events = query_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'meta_key' => 'event_date',
    'meta_compare' => '>=',
    'meta_value' => date ('Y-m-d'),
    'meta_type'  => 'DATE',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => '99',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'paged' => $paged
) );

// Iterate over events
foreach($events as $key => $event){

  // Get event date from post meta
  $event_date = get_post_meta($event->ID, 'event_date', $single = true);

  // Cache event month/year
  $event_month = date('F Y', strtotime($event_date));

  // Open new group if new month
  if($current_month != $event_month){
    if($key !== 0) echo '</ul>';  
    echo "<h2>{$event_month}</h2>";
    echo '<ul>';  
  }     

  // Add event date as new list item
  echo "<li>{$event_date}</li>";

  // Cache $curret_month
  $current_month = $event_month;        
}

// Close the last list if query had events
if(count($events)) echo '</ul>';
```

### EDIT

To update this solution to work for a post type archive, instead of the above add the following to your theme's functions.php, or a file included from it:

```
/**
 * Get event date 
 *
 * @return string
 */
function get_event_date() {

    /** @global WP_Post $post */
    global $post;

    /** Get event date from post meta */
    return get_post_meta($post->ID, 'event_date', $single = true);
}

/**
 * Get event month/year formatted
 *
 * @param string $event_date
 * 
 * @return string
 */
function format_event_date($event_date) {
    return date('F Y', strtotime($event_date));
}

/**
 * Order events archive by event date post meta
 *
 * @param WP_Query $query
 *
 * @return WP_Query
 */
function events_archive_pre_get_posts($query) {
    if (!$query->is_main_query() || !is_post_type_archive('event')) return $query;
    $query->set('meta_key', 'event_date');
    $query->set('meta_compare', '>=');
    $query->set('meta_value', date('Y-m-d'));
    $query->set('meta_type', 'DATE');
    $query->set('posts_per_page', 2);
    $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value');
    $query->set('order', 'ASC');
    return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'events_archive_pre_get_posts');
```

Then you can set posts per page to the number desired and pagination will work as expected. Here is a sample post type archive template which can be used to add the date headers between neatly formatted HTML lists, or at least they were until SO converted tabs to spaces:

```
<?php // Template header
get_header(); ?>


<?php /** @global WP_Query */
global $wp_query; ?>

<?php // Events archive loop
for($previous_month = ''; have_posts(); $previous_month = $formatted_date): the_post();

    // Get event date from post meta
    $event_date = get_event_date();

    // Format event month/year
    $formatted_date = format_event_date($event_date);

    // The formatted date is the first or not the same as previous event
    if($previous_month != $formatted_date):

        // Close previous list if this is not the first
        if($wp_query->current_post !== 0) echo "\n\t</ul>\n"; 

        // New month template ?>
    <h2><?php echo $formatted_date; ?></h2>
<?php
        // Open new list
        echo "\t<ul>\n";
    endif; 

    // Event post template ?>
        <li><?php echo $event_date; ?></li>
<?php endfor;

// Reset query 
wp_reset_query();

// Close the last list if query had events 
if(have_posts()) echo "\t</ul>\n"; ?>


<?php // Pagination
the_posts_pagination(); ?>


<?php // Template footer
get_footer();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But I don't get it. If I paste it in my code and change the meta_key to the name of my meta_key, it shows an empty list. If I add my query from the question, it shows a list of all event dates and no headlines for the month. and I also don't understand how I implement it in my code so I have the event-data (title, link,...) in the list as well.

Comment: thanks, now it works. just two things... 1. the <ul> elements opens in each other. there seems to be an error with the closing tag. I think I could figure that out. My bigger question is how I could print the event dates (title, permalink, excerpt,...). If I echo the title it always shows the same for all events.

Comment: I posted too quickly and should of corrected my answer first. I saw the data type conflict and assumed that was the only bug, posted then realised there were several other bugs with the formatting as you describe with the nested `<ul>` s. I don't have time at the moment to include why the original didn't work but I have updated my answer with a tested solution. The only testing I did when I posted the comment was with `query_posts()` with test custom posts on a fresh install and `var_dump()` as you said it had returned no data but did on my test site.

Comment: If use of `'posts_per_page' => '99'` and `'paged' => $paged` is not for pagination and just to get all posts, these two lines are not required and setting `'numberposts' => -1,` instead will prevent WP_Query from limiting the query results.

Comment: thanks, that's working. is there any way to use this with pagination?

Comment: Its for the custom post type archive

Comment: I've removed some of my comments since the link appeared to continue in chat, as they are not helpful to others going forward and I have updated my answer for filtering the main query instead with a sample `archive-event.php` to cover both scenarios

Answer (score 1):

You could store the current looping month in a variable and check if you're still looping in the same month.

Suppose `$events` is an array of all the events you want to display as an instance of `WP_Post`.

```
$current = 0;

foreach($events as $event){

    $eventDate = get_field('event_date', $event->ID);
    $month = date('m', strtotime($eventDate));

    // New month
    if($current != $month){
        $current = $month;
        // Perform actions of new month
    }

    // Perform normal actions for the event

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast response! But I don't know how to add your code to my query :-(